# multiple facebook comments, multiple tweets(multiaccount)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter

I am not a big expert on Facebook and Twitter APIs and I would definitely appreciate some introduction and possible guidance in my project.

This is what I am trying to do, and I wonder first of all if this is even possible.

I am building WP widget with checkbox option for user to allow generation of comment on his facebook wall and tweet with his twitter account. Comment is supposed to pick up values from custom input fields and build itself that way.

Simultaneously I want to generate post on my fb and twitter accounts regarding new user using my widget.

Is this possible to do? Could you give me links to documentation that is essential to make this one work. Otherwise what is your suggestion as a closest alternative effect.

Many many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm - looks similar to your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627031/facebook-like-comments-without-fb-buttons/10654466#10654466). I explained there how you should start with FB. With Twitter, it's very similar:

1. First you need to create an app: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new
2. Using that app's credentials, you have to ask user to allow your app to post on user's behalf (i.e. you need to obtain an access token): https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens
3. After you have access token, you can use REST API to do whatever you want: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api - including posting a tweet.

Regarding:

> Simultaneously I want to generate post on my fb and twitter accounts
>   regarding new user using my widget.

it's no different from the above approach - but you should use your own twitter account name (or /me/ in Facebook). Of course you have to authorize your own app to do that.