# facebook like/comments without fb buttons

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am not very fond of Facebook API so it would be great if somebody could tell me if this is even possible and then maybe give some guidance in what should I be reading.

I am building WP widget that has a checkbox option for user to share few generated words on his fb wall whether through like, comments, or whatever else is there that fb allows and has a feature for.
So once user hits save this action should occur in the background, building custom message by picking up input from some of Widget fields.
Once again is this possible and what should I be after???

Many many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all you should create FB application: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/
2. Suppose your webpage has text box and a button - Post to Facebook. When that button is clicked, you should display FB dialog asking user to grant permissions to your application to post on user's wall: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/. For that particular purpose you have to request [publish_actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/publishing/) permission.
3. After user confirms that, you will get **ACCESS TOKEN** from that popup - which you can use to post new message to user's wall using Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/. Depending on your technology, you might have SDK available for you which hids low-level details from you - but in essence, you only need to send POST HTTP request with required fields set (see link above for the list of fields).