# Discount for Twitter or Facebook post

Tags: facebook, twitter, response, discount

Create a pricing discount for users who post a pre designed message to facebook or twitter.

Is there a third party solution?

Any help with the any of the steps generally outlined below would be gratefully received.

from payment page:

- open twitter/facebook login (allow customer to login)
- automatically fill post with pre designed text
- let customer press post and receive authentication that they have done so
- re focus browser to payment page in some way (close fb/twitter pop up)
- update payment page to include discount if correct response is received

Comment: automatically fill post in not possible

Comment: @Dhiraj Bodicherla thanks Dhiraj. Any ideas if this can be achieved with Twitter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your plan violates at least 2 items in [facebook policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) - you are not allowed to auto fill the post field, nor you can incentivize users for using FB:

> **IV. Application Integration Points**
>
> 1 - You must not incentivize users to use (or gate content behind the use
>   of) Facebook social channels, or imply that an incentive is directly
>   tied to the use of our channels.
>
> 2 - You **must not pre-fill** any of the
>   fields associated with the following products, unless the user
>   manually generated the content earlier in the workflow: **Stream stories**
>   (user_message parameter for Facebook.streamPublish and
>   FB.Connect.streamPublish, and message parameter for stream.publish),
>   Photos (caption), Videos (description), Notes (title and content),
>   Links (comment), and Jabber/XMPP.

Comment: Ah, thanks avs099. I should have guessed. I have checked Twitter's terms and they don't seem to share the same policy. Any ideas how this can be achieved with Twitter?

Comment: re: twitter - take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10654616/1246870 - i explained how to get started. After that you can use REST API to POST to statuses/update to  post a tweet with predefined text: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update

Comment: if that helped you, please mark the answer as a solution then

Comment: Sorry avs, didn't think I had enough rep. many thanks for your help.